# HDMI output problem with late-2013 13 inch macbook pro with retina

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

I just bought late-2013 13-inch MacBook Pro with retina.
I want to connect it to my Samsung 32'' TV at home and DELL u2412m monitor at work. None of these connection is working right now.

MacOS X 10.9 display preferences tells me that a display is connected, and enlarge the screen to it, but no picture on the display is showing. I also try to mirror my screen to external hdmi-connected display with the same lack of "result": no picture.

Can one help me?

**Update**: Logs while connecting external tv:

```
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Found 29 modes for display 0x04280600 [18, 11]
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Found 47 modes for display 0x003f003e [19, 20]
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x003f003e changed state to online
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 29 modes available
     Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004693, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
     texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
     off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fa798e0c6c0) - enabling OpenGL
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004693, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
     texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: GL mask 0x4; bounds (1280, 0)[1920 x 1080], 47 modes available
     Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4c2d, Model 7c0, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xa43d659548bd7b4d2bb2194aa4abd5b3
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2306, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
     off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display added
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display removed
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 29 modes available
     Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004693, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
     texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
     off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004693, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
     texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: GL mask 0x4; bounds (-1920, 0)[1920 x 1080], 47 modes available
     Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4c2d, Model 7c0, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xa43d659548bd7b4d2bb2194aa4abd5b3
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fa798e0c3e0) - enabling OpenGL
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004693, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
     texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2305, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
     off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
     UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7fa798e0c000  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Nov 22 02:40:27 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x0b41f002 device: 0x7fa798e0c3e0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Nov 22 02:40:29 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Nov 22 02:40:29 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:29 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[109]: Display 0x0b41f002: Unit 2; ColorProfile { 2, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Nov 22 02:40:36 andreys-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 5 of Hub at 0x14000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
Nov 22 02:40:51 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Yandex.Disk[220]: -[YDSystemStateController checkRestart]
Nov 22 02:40:51 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Yandex.Disk[220]: -[YDOperationCenter performCheckRestartOperation]
Nov 22 02:40:51 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Yandex.Disk[220]: -[YDOperationCenter performCheckRestartOperation] --- appState GLOBAL=Synced USERINFO=Received CORE=Started SYNC=Idle EXOP=NO SHROP=NO PROXY=YES PHSTUP=Idle BLOCK=NO SLEEP=NO
Nov 22 02:41:07 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[859]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Nov 22 02:41:07 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[859]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Nov 22 02:41:07 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[859]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Nov 22 02:41:07 andreys-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[859]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
```

**Update 2**: just booted into ubuntu 13.10 (from usb stick) - the same problem as on mac - ubuntu display preferences tells me that a display is connected, buy no picture on the display is showing.

Looks like a hardware problem on my mac (or, a little change, efi one)...

**Update 3**: I forgot to update this later back. So. This was a hardware problem and Apple replace my macbook with new one (may be because it was less than 2 weeks in use and the problem was there since the begining).

Comment: Did you manage to get this issue resolved? I'm having the exact same issue on my late-2013 13-inch MacBook Pro with retina.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar one on MBP Early-2013 (15 Inch Retina) with HDMI port. Running Yosemite. But today I've updated CUDA drivers for GT650M and suddenly HDMI ports started working just like it used to have before. Try it. It may help you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already changed that particular device to a new one. But thanks for your advise - this might help others with the same problem.