# HDMI port on MBPr 13" (late 2013 11,1) stopped working after 10.10.4 upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, hdmi

I used to connect my MBPr HDMI port to my office ASUS MX299 display every morning for like a year, and everything was just fine. Recently I have updated to 10.10.4, with external display detached. That I connected it again and have been working as usually for the rest of the day. Next day I went to business trip. This morning I got back to office and routinely connected external display to hdmi port. It didn't work.

It's definitely not the cable, or display problem, because the same display works over the same cable with mdp-hdmi adaptor just fine.

What I tried so far:

- removing /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.* and ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.* files
- removing color profile for failing display
- resetting SMC
- booting into safe mode

No luck.

I can go with mdp-hdmi adaptor for sure, but that's not really convenient since I have both TB ports busy (one with 1Gb Ethernet adaptor, second with a TB disk). So I would like to revive HDMI port.

The first of two following logs shows connecting display to HDMI port -- display flicks and then shows no signal.

The second log shows connecting to TB (With mdh-hdmi adaptor) port -- display works just fine.

I failed to find any hint of a problem.

Hopefully someone could feed me with a clue?

```
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
WindowServer[163]: Found 27 modes for display 0x04280600 [27, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
WindowServer[163]: Found 27 modes for display 0x04280600 [27, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80007003, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display added
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display removed
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7f80cb509580  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
WindowServer[163]: Found 27 modes for display 0x04280600 [27, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80001003, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display added
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display removed
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7f80cb509580  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2321]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2320]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2322]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2323]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2324]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
```

```
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280600
WindowServer[163]: Found 27 modes for display 0x04280600 [27, 0]
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
WindowServer[163]: Found 47 modes for display 0x003f003d [34, 5]
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003d changed state to online
WindowServer[163]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
WindowServer[163]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
WindowServer[163]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x1a4a9ead: GL mask 0x2; bounds (-2560, 0)[2560 x 1080], 47 modes available
ed, Vendor 469, Model 2931, S/N 1d2ef, Unit 1, Rotation 0
f82f25829c9cb145a, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80005003, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1: Startup Mode 2560 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80005000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display added
WindowServer[163]: CGXDisplaysDidReconfigure: Display removed
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
 enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
9c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
nGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
dor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
fffffffffffffffff
WindowServer[163]: Display 0x1a4a9ead: GL mask 0x2; bounds (-2560, 0)[2560 x 1080], 47 modes available
ed, Vendor 469, Model 2931, S/N 1d2ef, Unit 1, Rotation 0
f82f25829c9cb145a, ColorSpace { 452990950 }
WindowServer[163]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7f80cb710350) - enabling OpenGL
WindowServer[163]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003aa3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
wport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
WindowServer[163]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7f80cb509580  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
WindowServer[163]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x1a4a9ead device: 0x7f80cb710350  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
WindowServer[163]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
DMProxy[2343]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2344]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2345]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
DMProxy[2346]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD initializing devices
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
WindowServer[163]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x1a4a9ead: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 452990950 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[526]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
```

Comment: Is basically the same as http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111340/5472 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar one on MBP Early-2013 (15 Inch Retina) with HDMI port. Running Yosemite. But today I've updated CUDA drivers for GT650M and suddenly HDMI ports started working just like it used to have before. Try it. It may help you as well.

Comment: MBP 13" comes with Intel Iris GPU, so I'm afraid that wouldn't work for me.